# reactjs datagrid use html

Tags: datagrid, reactjs

Im using the datagrid component [here](https://github.com/zippyui/react-datagrid)

I would like to use html in one of the fields and show a link or a picture etc. 
I tried using the render function for the column as below

```
var columns = [
    { name = 'field' },
    { name = 'link',render : function(uri) { return '<a href="'+uri+'">link</a>'} },
];
```

however it prints out the html as text

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default React escapes HTML, in order to prevent [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29). You can by pass this, by using the `prop` `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

However, as the name suggests, this leads to a vulnerability. I would suggest instead to use [Mardown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote), especially the [marked package](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

You can write a general component like this one and then use it everywhere.

```
import React from 'react';
import marked from 'marked';

const Markdown = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const raw = marked(this.props.text, {sanitize: true});
        return  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />;
    }

});
```

In your case then

```
var columns = [
    { name = 'field' },
    { name = 'link', render : function(uri) { return <Markdown text={'[link](' + uri + ')'} />} },
];
```

Comment: Yes I know this however can you point out how exactly I can achieve this without modifying the datagrid code. Note that the data grid takes column parameters only in specific format.

Comment: Before you answered this, I came up with a simpler solution that does not involve using markdown and provides more flexibility,  I just created a new reactClass , named it Linkify and the render  function returned : `return ( <Linkify link={link} title={title} />)`  . But thanks for the help

Comment: Of course, I went for Markdown because you said that you wanted to include
> link, images, etc.
therefore I thought you were looking for a way to insert HTML in general.

Answer (score 1):

First I created a class which will output a link

```
var Linkify = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return (
             <a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.title}</a>
       )
   },
});
```

Then used this class in the render function

```
 var columns = [
{ name : 'edit', render : function(id){
        var editlink = "http://www.example.com/id="+id;
        return ( <Linkify link={editlink} title="edit" />)
    }  
},
```

This way any html can be used in the datagrid column by simply using the react component.